# Pine vs Cedar for patio furniture on screen porch

Tags: woodworking, patio, wooden-furniture

I am building a patio furniture couch following this design, along with some patio furniture coushions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yKXtv3v8tg

I intend to put this on my screen porch which is mostly dry but gets some rain blowing in every now and then. I have a gallon of this stain which is already on other cedar furniture that I want this piece to match somewhat:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Olympic-Maximum-1-gal-Redwood-Semi-Transparent-Exterior-Stain-and-Sealant-in-One-79552A-01/305230164

I am having trouble finding good cedar lumber in my area though. Would this be an ok situation to use non pressure treated pine instead with the stain mentioned above since the area is mostly dry? Or will I be risking rot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While cedar is certainly more rot-resistant, pine should be fine.

Should not even need to be pressure treated, since the area is mostly dry.

Comment: I agree that rot is not an issue here, but I don't like pine because it oftentimes contains so much sap.  That can seep out later and make a sticky mess in places, esp. where there are knots. just my humble opinion.

Comment: By skipping pressure treated, you can go for kiln-dried and have less issues with pitch pockets.

Comment: I find southern pine much stronger than cedar; may be important depending on the design.